# Vector space over field span the same space .

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let V be vector space over field  $R$, and $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in V$.
> Prove that span(B) = span(A), when $B= \{v_1 + 2 v_2, v_1 + v_2 - v_3,
>  5v_3\}$ and $A = \{v_1, 4v_2, 6v_3\}$

It's clearly to prove that when $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are independent.
But I don't have idea how to show without this assumption.

Comment: Note:  $\begin{vmatrix}1&2&0\\1&1&-1\\0&0&5\end{vmatrix}$ and $\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&6\end{vmatrix}$ are non-zero

Comment: @J.W.Tanner where is good explanation for this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need LI.

Show that each of the vectors in $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $B$ and vice versa.

It is clear for set $B$. But to express each vector in $A$ as a linear combination of vectors in $B$, consider the following:
\begin{align*}
v_1&=\color{red}{-1}(v_1+2v_2)+\color{red}{2}(v_1+v_2-v_3)+\color{red}{\frac{2}{5}}(5v_3)\\
4v_2&=\color{red}{4}(v_1+2v_2)-\color{red}{4}(v_1+v_2-v_3)-\color{red}{\frac{4}{5}}(5v_3)\\
6v_3&=\color{red}{\frac{6}{5}}(5v_3).
\end{align*}
Thus $A \subset \text{Span}(B)$, consequently $\text{Span}(A) \subseteq \text{Span}(B)$